# Agrupar por elementos en Python

Tags: python, lista, bucles, agrupación

Tengo este código el cual agrupa por el primer elemento:

```
from itertools import groupby
result = []
seleccion=[('201', 'Danilo', 480, 4202), ('201', 'Danilo', 240, 1988), ('306', 'Ricardo', 360, 3186)]
if seleccion:
    f = lambda x: x[:2]
    for key, group in groupby(sorted(seleccion, key=f), f):
        result.append((key, *map(sum, zip(*(l[2:] for l in group)))))
    print(result)
```

Obtengo como resultado:

```
[(('201', 'Danilo'), 720, 6190), (('306', 'OSVALDO_TARIFEÑO_NAVIA'), 360, 3186)]
```

Pero lo que necesito es que me lo deje asi:

```
[('201', 'Danilo', 720, 6190), ('306', 'OSVALDO_TARIFEÑO_NAVIA', 360, 3186)]
```

La idea es que me los agrupe por el primer elemento (201 o 306) luego que agrupe por nombre (201, Danilo o 201, Ricardo) y luego me sume el 3 elemento y cuarto elemento (eso ya lo hace)

Si alguien me puede ayudar. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que la solución sea tan simple como añadir un asterisco `*` a tu código.

Concretamente, delante de `key` cuando haces el `.append()` a la lista `result`, así:

```
from itertools import groupby
result = []
seleccion=[('201', 'Danilo', 480, 4202), ('201', 'Danilo', 240, 1988), ('306', 'Ricardo', 360, 3186)]
if seleccion:
    f = lambda x: x[:2]
    for key, group in groupby(sorted(seleccion, key=f), f):
        result.append((*key, *map(sum, zip(*(l[2:] for l in group)))))
    print(result)
```

El resultado sale así:

```
[('201', 'Danilo', 720, 6190), ('306', 'Ricardo', 360, 3186)]
```

La explicación es que el `*` "expande" la tupla que tienes en `key`, convirtiéndola a una serie de valores separados por comas, que quedan entonces formando parte de la tupla que estás añadiendo a `result`. Es decir, eliminas un nivel de anidamiento.

Aunque el resultado en este ejemplo sale lo que pedías, no estoy del todo seguro de que este método sea general para producir lo que dices en el enunciado: una agrupación primero por el número y luego por el nombre. Sería necesario un ejemplo con datos de entrada más complejos para verificarlo (además de que `groupby()` requiere que estén previamente ordenados por la clave que usarás para agruparlos).

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevaba horas buscando alguna alternativa